# RadioGroup control not running properly

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

Hi everybody I have been working on the same issue  for hours.What I wanted to achieve is to set my fonts to `TextView`  and Its finally done.However I am having trouble with `RadioGroup`The problem is that when I run my app and checked RadioButton It seems working.Then I have noticed that the other RadioButton is not working.I wasnt able to set anything to Textview When I click on that  What am i doing wrong here

Here what I have so far

@EDIT

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rdg, int arg1) {

        ///this is where I need help.How can i set returning values
        RadioButton Che= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Che);
        RadioButton Ser= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ser);

         if(arg1 ==R.id.Che ){
              cutomfonts=getFirstFont();
              myTextView.setTypeface(cutomfonts);
        }else if(arg1 == R.id.ser){
              cutomfonts=getSecondFont();
              myTextView.setTypeface(cutomfonts);
        }   



}
```

This is Xml File

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="158dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Che"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge your you are not register `Che` or `ser` radiobutton, Eclipse not find xml defined `Che` and `ser` RadioButton value in java file. So you first register do following things,

```
Che= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Che);
ser= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ser);
```

after using above code you can try to run it's work perfect. also i put my own code using if else this is also work for you,
Now you can implement `onCheckedChanged()` override method in following way,

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    if(arg1 == R.id.Che){
          cutomfonts=getFirstFont();
          myTextView.setTypeface(cutomfonts);
    }else if(arg1 == R.id.ser){
          cutomfonts=getSecondFont();
          myTextView.setTypeface(cutomfonts);
    }   
}
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you for replying.I have edited my post as you suggested I Think I did something wrong .Because Eclips highlihts these two variable and says "you never use "themWhat Am i doing wrong

Comment: yes, you doing wrong because eclipse not find xml defined value in java file. so you check my answer first two line code findViewById to get your xml radiobutton. You welcome :)